# Retrieve id of model created in $afterInsert hook in Objection ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, objection.js

Is it possible to retrieve (at least) the id of created model in $afterInsert hook in Objection ORM?

```
  async $afterInsert(queryContext)
```

I guess and hope it could be available somehow from queryContext?

The goal is to be able to log this id when created in an allowed graph through insertGraph method.

Comment: Have you tried `this.id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the returned data at `this`:

```
  async $afterInsert(queryContext) {
    await super.$afterInsert(queryContext);
    console.log(this.id)
  }
```